# Recognizing lines and silhouettes added by Paint

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have a couple of photos. Some of these have lines, circles and hands added by Paint. I would like to recognize a photo that has handwritten silhouettes or primitives colored by a single color.

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this? Please share the code that you have written so far.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the photos. What are you hoping to do after determining whether the photos have been Paint-ed on, because using OpenCV for this is overkill if that is your entire goal...

Comment: The answer may be different for files saved as BMP/PNG (lossless) versus JPEG (lossy) so please clarify that too.

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to separate all 3 RGB channels of your source image, then apply some classic gaussian blur and adaptive threshold and `findCountour()` method on your 3 channels.

To extract all 3 RGB channels, use this code ([source](http://answers.opencv.org/question/59529/how-do-i-separate-the-channels-of-an-rgb-image-and-save-each-one-using-the-249-version-of-opencv/)):

```
Mat src = imread("img.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); //load  image

Mat bgr[3];   //destination array
split(src,bgr);//split source  

//Note: OpenCV uses BGR color order
imwrite("blue.png",bgr[0]); //blue channel
imwrite("green.png",bgr[1]); //green channel
imwrite("red.png",bgr[2]); //red channel
```